# Where Call and Apply functions are defined in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can some one please let me know where call and apply functions are defined in java script.
Initially i thought they are defined in Function.prototype object that why all functions inherit them from there.But when I do Function.prototype (in Crome console)it gives me function Empty() {}.

Can someone please let me know where these function comes from and why Function.prototype points to empty method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should do `console.dir(Function.prototype)` and click on the arrow to list its properties.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the correct behaviour.  [The specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), section 15.4.3, says:

> The Function prototype object is
>   itself a Function object (its
>   [[Class]] is "Function") that, when
>   invoked, accepts any arguments and
>   returns undefined.

All functions are objects in JS and though `Function.prototype` is, in fact, a function itself is no reason that `call` and `apply` can't be inherited from this object.

If you read further in section 15.4.3, you will see that `apply` and `call` are members of `Function.prototype`.

**Hint:** Chrome, by default, outputs Functions as strings (`Function.prototype.toString`).  You can force it to display all it's properties á la an Object tree by using `console.dir`:

```
console.dir(Function.prototype);
```

Comment: Thanks Andy that helps.But when i do Object.prototype or Number.prototype in crome it display the properties straight away.Object and Number are also constructors i.e Functions i.e Objects.Why this special behaviour for Function object. ?

Comment: The chain has to start somewhere! Because Object is a Function, it's internal [[prototype]] is Function.prototype, its public prototype is Object.prototype, whose [[prototype]] is null. That's where the chain ends. Read ECMA-262 §15.2, it's all explained.

Comment: @Gopal: `Object` and `Number` are functions, but `Object.prototype` and `Number.prototype` are objects.  `Function.prototype` *is* a function, I'm not sure why and I can't find any discussion on it, but that's just how it is in the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Function.prototype);
//["bind", "arguments", "toString", "length", "call", "name", "apply", "caller", "constructor"]
```

The reason you did not see them is because built-in object properties/functions are often **non-enumerable**. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` is a function designed to list properties of an object regardless of enumerability. It is also a relatively recent addition that comes with the EMCAScript 5 spec, but Chrome should support it fine.

Comment: Thanks!! that helps.But when i do Object.prototype or Number.prototype in crome it display the properties straight away.Object and Number are also constructors i.e functions.Why this special behaviour for Function. ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the source code for [`Function.prototype.apply`](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/FunctionPrototype.cpp) from JavaScriptCore (Nitro) in WebKit

```
EncodedJSValue JSC_HOST_CALL functionProtoFuncApply(ExecState * exec) {
    JSValue thisValue = exec - > hostThisValue();
    CallData callData;
    CallType callType = getCallData(thisValue, callData);
    if (callType == CallTypeNone) return throwVMTypeError(exec);

    JSValue array = exec - > argument(1);

    MarkedArgumentBuffer applyArgs;
    if (!array.isUndefinedOrNull()) {
        if (!array.isObject()) return throwVMTypeError(exec);
        if (asObject(array) - > classInfo() == & Arguments::s_info) asArguments(array) - > fillArgList(exec, applyArgs);
        else if (isJSArray( & exec - > globalData(), array)) asArray(array) - > fillArgList(exec, applyArgs);
        else if (asObject(array) - > inherits( & JSArray::s_info)) {
            unsigned length = asArray(array) - > get(exec, exec - > propertyNames().length).toUInt32(exec);
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            applyArgs.append(asArray(array) - > get(exec, i));
        } else return throwVMTypeError(exec);
    }

    return JSValue::encode(call(exec, thisValue, callType, callData, exec - > argument(0), applyArgs));
}
```

If you want to you can hunt through the V8 and JaegerMonkey source to find their implementations. I couldn't find them myself.  If someone wants to point me to the source or those then that's cool :)